# Running a t.test in R, data are essentially constant

Tags: r, statistics

**I am trying to construct a t.test using a Hi/Lo method. 
But I am getting an error, this is my code:**

```
##hi/lo version 
dat = read.csv("parking.csv", comment.char = "#", as.is = TRUE)


dat = dat[dat$prepost!="" & !is.na(dat$viol_pc) , ];
dat = dat[, c("wbcode","country","viol_pc", "prepost","corruption")]


dat$hilo = ifelse(dat$corruption > 0.33, "hi", "lo")


pp_hilo = t.test(dat$hilo[dat$prepost=="pre"], dat$hilo[dat$prepost=="pos"])
```

**The error I get is**

> Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Please edit as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: dat$hilo = ifelse(dat$corruption > 0.33, "hi", "lo") : This makes dat$hilo a character / factor.  You are doing a t.test on factors.. this is not correct. Is there a typo somewhere? Which column are u supposed to test?